# Understanding how classes work in Java

Tags: java, python, function, class

I'm new to programming, and I started by learning python. However, now I'm watching a lecture series online by Stanford, and they use Java.

I'm having a hard time transitioning from Python to Java. Can someone please explain how classes work in Java in contrast to functions in Python? Public vs. Private seems strange. I've also heard 'methods' and been told they are similar to functions. Links to videos or other explanations are welcomed.

I realize this question does not have any code; but we all have to start somewhere. Thanks

Comment: Spend some time studying a specific language, having someone discuss two languages is way too broad.

Comment: Python also has classes, but they are an option vs. Java requiring them.  I found it easier to learn about classes in Python first.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  StackOverflow is for _specific_ programming questions and is not a general tutorial/discussion site. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] to understand what is appropriate here.

Comment: If you're talking about the Stanfurd CS106A videos with Mehran Sahami, they're excellent. Stick with them, but do yourself this favor: forget about Python. Forget you ever learned anything about classes. Forget comparing and contrasting languages. Just listen and learn what's right in front of you, and when you get more experience, then you can do the comparative thing, and find that it all makes sense.

Comment: @JimGarrison arguably, since programmers.SE would just flame the *** out of this question, I think we can accept it being posted here - Aaron is asking for assistance, and there aren't really any viable alternative forums to get it. Understandably answers will be subjective, but part of a good answer is keeping opinion out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it better to take a step back and learn the basics of [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), not necessarily related to Java specifically.

Some places to get you started:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5kfCH50wl0

This is just a few, though you will find many more learning material around the web.